# USB function controller emulation in QEMU

Tags: function, controller, usb, qemu

Does QEMU provide emulation for any target with USB device controller? Actually I am developing an embedded linux based device and was thinking about testing it on QEMU.

BR,
Mooni

Answer (score 2):

You can find this information in the [QEMU Manual](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html), section "3.9 USB emulation":

> QEMU emulates a PCI UHCI USB
>   controller. You can virtually plug
>   virtual USB devices or real host USB
>   devices (experimental, works only on
>   Linux hosts). Qemu will automatically
>   create and connect virtual USB hubs as
>   necessary to connect multiple USB
>   devices.

There you also find all relevant configuration parameters.

The USB Controller is provided for the following targets:

- PC System
- MIPS/malta has a PIIX4 PCI/USB/SMbus controller
- ARM: has various options

Comment: Actually USB emulation in QEMU is only in PC System emulation mode. I am not talking about PC System emulation mode.
I am developing a USB device for an embedded (non PC) target. I can not use PC System emulation mode and QEMU provides USB emulation only in PC System emulation mode.
I want some way to test my USB device without hardware on QEMU or on any other emulation/simulation platform.

Comment: @Mooni: searching in the docs for "USB" brought the information you're looking for. I have copied it into the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this as well. There is a bit of code for virtual usb devices in the repo but I'm specifically looking for a way to write a dcd (device controller driver) which can be accessed as a virtual device from the host running the qemu simulation. I'm looking for a way to implement this for stm32 family.